# 'Updating Clock' via Reactjs (Using JSX)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this code, with which I would like to make a clock updating every second.

```js
const DigitalTime = function DigitalTime(props){
    return <div>{props.time}</div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<DigitalTime time={(new Date()).toLocaleString()}/>,get("content"));
```

`get` is an alias of `document.getElementbyID`

Earlier I had done this with a `react component` like this:

```js
class DateTime extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={ currentTime:(new Date()).toLocaleString()};
        this.start();
    }
    start(){
        setInterval(
            ()=>{
                this.setState(
                    {currentTime:(new Date()).toLocaleString()}
                )
            },1000
        )
    }
    render(){
        return (
        <div>Current Time is : {this.state.currentTime}</div>
        )
    }
};
```

But I would like to do this via `function`. I tried making a variable and updating it with `setInterval` but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to write this code as function component? You should show a minimal effort, you have a lot of examples in React docs

Answer (score 0):

https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

this is a nice article by dan abramov on how it works and how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hooks.

Create an interval timer using `setInterval` in `useEffect`, and `clearInterval` in `useEffect`s [`cleanup`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) when the component unmount.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const DigitalTime = function DigitalTime(props){
  const [time, setTime] = useState(props.time);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date().toLocaleString())
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
    
  }, []);
  
  return <div>Current Time is: {time}</div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<DigitalTime time={(new Date()).toLocaleString()}/>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
const DigitalTime = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
      setInterval(() => {
        setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
      }, 1000);
  });
  
  return <div>{time}</div>
}

 ReactDOM.render(<DigitalTime />, document.getElementById('root'));
```